# width:100% doesn't work on mobile browser

Tags: html, css, mobile, width, browser

First of all i must say that i tried all solutions on this site. I want to set `width:100%` on main div. It work on desktop browsers but not on mobile browsers. Here is css of my main div:

```
.main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -66px;
    opacity: 0.83;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px #CCC;
       -moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #CCC;
            box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
}
```

body is defined:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    width: 100%;    
    height: 1100px;
    background-color: #222930;
}
```

Header is set to 100% too:

```
.header {
    height: 93px;
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #F0EBEB;
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
}
```

I tried:

- set `min-width: 100%;` to body, header, main
- set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />`
- `<meta name="viewport" content="width=800" />`
- `transform: scale(.5);` ...

What is problem?

Edit: when the page load div is on 100%. But i can scroll to right for 100px or more px. `overflow-x: hidden;` doesn't work.

Comment: `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`?

Comment: doesnt work. I tried overflow-x:hidden but it doesnt help. When the page load it is on 100%width but i can scroll to right.

Comment: screenshot? which mobile browser is this failing in?

Comment: i finally resolve it with overflow-x:hidden for body.

Comment: also- what's the HTML context? what's in your head element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with Safari Browser. You can fix it by creating CSS viewport, or by adding `min-width` to CSS. 
Try `min-width: 980px;`

Comment: i resolve it finally with overflow-x:hidden; I don't try Safari.

Answer (score 3):

Finally it fix overflow-x:hidden. Page load with 100% width but i can scroll to right.

Comment: Funny how your own awnser is -1 and it was the only solution I found for my view problem, +1.

Comment: Dude, the problem you had 8 years ago saved my life today. Thanks to comeback and answer your own question