# Mobile browsers not supporting width 100%?

Tags: html, css, mobile, view, width

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732475/div-width-100-percent-not-working-in-mobile-browser) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105944/width100-doesnt-work-on-mobile-browser) but I was unable to find a suitable answer

I don't want to change the default view-port because everything else other than my footer scale beautifully. Strangely, I have a fixed position menu `<div>` that has always accepted the `width: 100%` value.

I have tried `width: 100%`, `width: 100vw`, and `width: inherit`. For some reason, a couple full-width images on my site wouldn't work with `width: 100%`, but took on the correct width when I used `width: inherit`.

Is there a solution in which I don't have to change the view-port size that I haven't thought of?

My menu `<div>` which works correctly:

```
#navbar {

    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 25px;
    background-color: #1391cb;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #3a3a3a;

}
```

My images which I got to correctly scale:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

    #main-content, #main-content-overlay {

        width: inherit;

    }

}
```

In addition, certain pages of my site work perfectly on mobile. There is no discernible pattern to which do, and which don't. Some of the pages that work have more content than the height of the device, and others don't. None of my pages exceed the width of the view-port in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: any examples of code?

Answer (score 0):

The only case I've seen width:100% being ignored, is if the parent container(s) do not have a width set.

Comment: The parent container is the body. `<html>` and `<body>` are both set to `width:100%`. It works perfectly on desktop, just not mobile devices.